# JavaScript code stops when losing focus

Tags: javascript, focus, delay, sleep

Our project uses a variety of libraries (Kinetic Js, jquery, buzz.js, etc..), we have a lot of animations going on and some sounds playing simultaneously ,our purpose is stop all the JavaScript processes when a user change the tab or the window of the browser, losing focus.

We know that the `onBlur` and `onFocus` gives us the ability to detect that change and with one `setTimeOut` function we can stop it. We want to know if there is a more efective way of doing that or a more low level solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: blur is only useful for elements that actually accept focus - not all do. Some browsers automatically postpone execution of some things when the tab or browser loses window focus (e.g. Chrome stops playing Flash, I think).  I would have thought a search along the lines of "detect if tab is currently active" would turn up something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These days, there's requestAnimationFrame() http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/webperf/raw-file/tip/specs/RequestAnimationFrame/Overview.html

Article with info about browser support, and how to emulate in browsers that do not support it: http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/.

Comment: We have animation and sound playing at the same time. When the current tab loses focus, the sound still plays, but the animation freeze. We use CreateJS to do the animation and BuzzJS to play the sound. 
Our problem is not CPU usage based, but to have control on the animation+sound.
What can we do to avoid the animation to freeze? Or, in the other side, how can we accomplish to stop both sound and animation, when it looses focus?

Comment: Are your sounds continuous or synchronised with your animation?

Comment: We try to have the sounds synchronized with the animation. Some of the animations contains parts of text, and the corresponding sound is someone dictating that text.

Comment: @JoséSilva I've also noticed this problem. Looks like it's a problem with the browser itself and the way it handles CSS-based animations. I don't think this problem happens if you have canvas animations because canvas animations are purely dependent on the implementation by us, not the browser vendor.